# Angular-cli component generator do not work inside Nativesctipt

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to learn `Angular` with `Nativescript`.

So, I installed `angular-cli` and `nativescript` on my windows 10 machine.

**Angular works fine by itself but when I want to generate component inside nativescript project, I have this error:**

[image: compare of angular with nativescript while generating component]

After a couple of times of research, I installed `@nativescript/schematics` from [THIS SOURCE](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/angular-cli):

> npm i -g @angular/cli
>
> npm i -g @nativescript/schematics **"tested with -D either"**

And after that I have this error:

[image: stack trace after install schematics]

Do you know what's my problem and how to solve this?

***Thanks in Advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why someone gave me `-1`;

There's still some extra command needed-`for me on windows 10 and tested on mac`- to work with:

> **`ng g c some-component`**

inside nativescript-angular project.

**These steps fixed my problem :**

> 1. tns create angularProject
> 2. npm i -D @nativescript/schematics
> 3. npm i @angular-devkit/schematics @angular-devkit/core @schematics/angular

and then you can simply use : ***`ng g c some-component`***

My `tns version` is **`6.8.0`** and my `angular-cli version` is **`10.0.4`** when I'm writing this answer.

Comment: Still gives me `The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.`

Answer (score -1):

Do

npm i -D @angular/cli @nativescript/schematics

(To make them both dev dependencies)

Then see here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/241